# checking blur image using java

Tags: java

I want to check the image that is blur or not. I didn't find any **JAVA API** which will identity the blur.I have seen the API which can make the image blur.

Since, I don't have any background in image processing. I am not able to proceed it.

Could anyone please help me in achieving this requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try Sikuli: http://doc.sikuli.org/finder.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are api's to do such thing, so you need to create your own. A good starting point to create the algorithm is to analyze every pixels of an image, or some random pixels to decrease processing time (but also decrease accuracy), look to the surrounding pixels and get the difference in the RGB values. The more the image is blurred, the lesser will be the difference on the pixel values.